# Scope issue while calling Backbone.js functions with jquery.aop

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, aop

I have been unable to call Backbone functions using jquery.AOP. It works well on global functions and javascript modules though.

```
require(['app', 'jquery' ], 
     function(App, $) {     
    App.initialize();
    $.aop.before( {target: App.appRouter 
               method: 'helloWorld'}, 
            function() { 
                 alert("before Hello World");
                } 
});
```

In my example, app.appRouter is definitely an alive instance variable.
Here is App with its appRouter:

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone'
], function($, 
        _, 
    Backbone
    ){

var appRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        //some code
    },
    helloWorld: function(){
                alert("hello world");
        }

});


var initialize = function(){
    this.appRouter = new appRouter(this);
    Backbone.history.start();

};


return {
       initialize: initialize,
       appRouter : this.appRouter
```

};
});

Seems like a scope problem as the before advice is never reached. 
Thanks for any thoughts,
Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue of timing.

$.aop works by replacing the target function with a new function, and maintaining a reference to the original target. When you call the function, the aop version of it is executed and it in turn calls the original function.

Given that, try swapping the `App.initialize()` call with the `$.aop...` call:

```
$.aop.before({
  target: App.appRouter 
  method: 'helloWorld'}, 
  function() { 
    alert("before Hello World");

});
App.initialize();
```

My other thought is that I don't see any place in your code that is calling the router's `helloWorld` method. Are you sure your actually calling it?

Comment: I've tried to swap both calls to no avail. And yes the fonction is called when a link is clicked leading to a Backbone router's route with the trigger option set to true. This may be a reason why jquery.aop cannot invoke it. However the App.appRouter.helloWorld function is well present in Firebug while debugging.

Comment: last idea, then: does your router have routes correctly defined on it? you don't show the actual `routes: {...}` in the code you posted. if there are no routes defined, the router won't do anything. ... sorry if that's obvious, just going off what i see in the post

Comment: Backbone Router is properly written with routes, events... however I've discovered something: By doing $.aop.before({ target: App.appRouter method: ''}, function() { alert("before Hello World"); }); , all functions of appRouter are aop-called correctly!Is there anyway to dynamically get the target and method inside the aop.before block? That could eventually lead me to the caller

Comment: ..it's like the 'helloWorld' method is not defined in the router or something. But when I do specify method:'', aop for all functions of the router works properly.